# Can I fire two select statements in a single MySQL command and count resulting rows?

Tags: mysql, select, count, rows

Here's my code as is, working, but very slow:

```
    $graded = R::getAll("SELECT posts.id, posts.discussion, rating.rating, rating.itemid
                             FROM uv_forum_posts posts
                             JOIN uv_rating rating ON ( posts.id = rating.itemid )
                             WHERE posts.discussion = :discussion_id
                             GROUP BY posts.userid",
                             array(':discussion_id' => $discussion['id']));

    $total = R::getAll("SELECT posts.userid
                        FROM uv_forum_posts posts
                        WHERE posts.discussion = :discussion_id
                        GROUP BY userid",
                        array(':discussion_id' => $discussion['id']));

    $percentages[] = count($graded) / count($total) * 100;
```

`$graded` represents all rows that have a rating.

`$total` represents all user participation, regardless of being graded or not.

I'm only interested in the numerical values of the resulting sets, can I combine these two MySQL calls into a single call that returns two numbers `graded` and `total`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your requirements you can try

```
SELECT p.userid,
       COUNT(*) total,
       COUNT(r.itemid) graded
  FROM uv_forum_posts p LEFT JOIN 
       uv_rating r ON p.id = r.itemid
 WHERE p.discussion = :discussion_id
 GROUP BY p.userid
```

Output:

```
| USERID | TOTAL | GRADED |
---------------------------
|      1 |     8 |      2 |
|      2 |     4 |      4 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6c7/1)**

**UPDATE:** If you just want grand total for all posts and users then

```
SELECT COUNT(*) total,
       COUNT(r.itemid) graded
  FROM uv_forum_posts p LEFT JOIN 
       uv_rating r ON p.id = r.itemid
 WHERE p.discussion = 1
```

Output:

```
| TOTAL | GRADED |
------------------
|    12 |      6 |
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f6c7/3)**

Comment: Thank you, this helped speed up the query significantly. It's still not quite there. Running this query I get what I want but then I need to add all `TOTAL` into `$total`and all `GRADED` into `$graded` manually in PHP. Is there some way to push this simple addition into MySQL so it just returns those values in the query itself? Thank you for your time and help!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use a query as in the format :

```
Select
( SELECT posts.id, posts.discussion, rating.rating, rating.itemid
                             FROM uv_forum_posts posts
                             JOIN uv_rating rating ON ( posts.id = rating.itemid )
                             WHERE posts.discussion = :discussion_id
                             GROUP BY posts.userid,
                             array(':discussion_id' => $discussion['id']))) gradeCount,

(SELECT posts.userid
                        FROM uv_forum_posts posts
                        WHERE posts.discussion = :discussion_id
                        GROUP BY userid,
                        array(':discussion_id' => $discussion['id'])))totalCount
```